# redirecting back with an array result in laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I redirect back in laravel and return with an array result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your code here instead of image.

Comment: `with()` function is for flash message. You should `return view('viewname', $data);

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
return redirect()->route('page.name')->with(['data' => $yourData]);
```

in view

```
session()->get('data')
```

Answer (score 0):

in controller:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('array', [$array]);
```

in view:

```
@foreach(session()->get('array')  as $arr)
   <tr>
      <td>{{$arr}}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```